# Is it possible to update React component, that is created with React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code, that creates dynamic table with dynamic number of rows - each row is React component (created by `createElement`):

```
 render() {
        var rows = this.props.data.map(function(rowData) {
            return React.createElement(ScheduleRow, {
                data: rowData
            });
        });
        this.state.rows = rows;
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    {rows}
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I can access each individual row by `this.state.rows[rowNumber]`, whose JSON stringify gives `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`, that is fine, unfortunately I can not explore the structure of this object.

So - my question is - can I call some methods on `this.state.rows[rowNumber]` with aim to update the style, data of this component? Or maybe I can even access the child components and update the style and data of some child component of `this.state.rows[rowNumber]`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why do u need `React.createElement` in this context when you could just call the element in JSX form as in:

`{ this.props.data.map(row => <ScheduleRow {...row} />) }`

But generally, a component is when it's `props`/`state` is updated. So when your `this.props.data` is modified the component shall rerender and update your child component.

**NOTE**: Do not set state using `this.state = //whatever`
checkout this article: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b